# Passing the value from a ruby block to a resource in chef

Tags: json, ruby, resources, chef-recipe

I am writing a chef resource, which will generate a password, and I am calling that resource in a recipe with the list of inputs.

Following is my scenario:  Once my resource got executed, a new set of passwords will be generated in a folder, and I want to retrieve that password which is newly generated.  But I am unable to retrieve that password because the value I am trying to retrieve is executing at the convergence phase.

Simple code block to explain my scenario:

```
Chef::Log.info("Creating new keys")
create_password 'New Password is being generated' do
   action :change_passwords
   password_util_dir node[:password][:passwd_util_dir]
   rgbu_chef node[:password][:rgbu_chef]
   old_data_bags node[:password][:old_data_bags]
   new_data_bags node[:password][:new_data_bags]
end
```

The code above will create new passwords in a folder.

Later, I am trying to take the passwords through a JSON Parser:

```
text =::File.read("#{new_password_dir}")
data_hash = JSON.parse(text)
new_wls_password = data_hash['rase_wlsadmin_pwd']
```

The #{new_password_dir} is the directory location of the newly created password.json file.

I am trying to use the value of "new_wls_password" in the another resource like below:

```
Chef::Log.info("Updating WLSADMIN Password")
passwd_backup 'Updating wlsadmin password' do
  action :update_wlsadmin
  osuser node[:password][:wls_config_user]
  usergroup node[:password][:wls_install_group]
  new_wls_password "#{new_wls_password}"
end
```

Here, the new password which I am trying to retrieve is empty, since the following three lines are executed in the first place:

```
text =::File.read("#{new_password_dir}")
    data_hash = JSON.parse(text)
    new_wls_password = data_hash['rase_wlsadmin_pwd']
```

So, by that time, the new passwords resource has not been run.

I tried many stack overflow suggestions, like:

1. putting those three lines in a ruby_block like this

```
ruby_block "new_password" do
    block do
        text =::File.read("#{new_password_dir}")
        data_hash = JSON.parse(text)
        node.set[:new_wls_password] = data_hash['rase_wlsadmin_pwd']
    end
end
```

Then I tried fetching the value into the resource as below

```
Chef::Log.info("Updating WLSADMIN Password")
    passwd_backup 'Updating wlsadmin password' do
      action :update_wlsadmin
      osuser node[:password][:wls_config_user]
      usergroup node[:password][:wls_install_group]
      new_wls_password "#{node[:new_wls_password]"
    end
```

With the above approach still the value is empty

2. Trying the value with lazy and calling that value.
3. Passing the value from one ruby block to another ruby block, which I can do, but not with the resources.

Please, can you help?

EDIT #1 : 
I need to pass the value from the resource to the template.
Something like this, after running the following resource:

```
Chef::Log.info("Creating new keys")
create_password 'New Password is being generated' do
   action :change_passwords
   password_util_dir node[:password][:passwd_util_dir]
   rgbu_chef node[:password][:rgbu_chef]
   old_data_bags node[:password][:old_data_bags]
   new_data_bags node[:password][:new_data_bags]
end
```

A new set of passwords will be generated in a folder, like the /tmp/password.json file.

After the resource execution above I am writing a template like:

```
template "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/domain.properties" do 
source 'domain_properties.erb' 
variables 
({ :domain_name => "#{domain_name}", 
   :admin_url => "#{admin_url}", 
   :new_wls_password => "#{new_wls_password}" })
end
```

Here, how can I parse the newly created value of "new_wls_password" ?

Comment: There can be couple of reasons, if you are getting empty value. Please post the "password.json" entry as well. Also, does it takes time to create a file with password for your resource `create_password`?

Comment: @ Mrigesh Priyadarshi :  password.json  file having the values like this  {
 {   "id": "ris_credentials",
    "mrep_rcu_pwd": "dy_06nrJAIhUud",
    "navteq_schema_pwd": "xH#3zIS9Q4Hc#B",
    "obiee_admin_pwd": "tY#98njEIIp6Ui",
}      And it never take so much time to generate passwords .The issue what i understood is the order of execution.Before the execution of "create_password" resource  the value is executed during the compilation phase - new_wls_password = data_hash['rase_wlsadmin_pwd']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy attribute like below:-

```
Chef::Log.info("Updating WLSADMIN Password")
passwd_backup 'Updating wlsadmin password' do
  action :update_wlsadmin
  osuser node[:password][:wls_config_user]
  usergroup node[:password][:wls_install_group]
  new_wls_password lazy { JSON.parse(File.read("/tmp/password.json"))['rase_wlsadmin_pwd'] }
end
```

Template resource can be written as:-

```
template "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/domain.properties" do 
   source 'domain_properties.erb' 
   variables (lazy{{ :domain_name => "#{domain_name}", 
       :admin_url => "#{admin_url}", 
       :new_wls_password => JSON.parse(File.read("/tmp/password.json"))['rase_wlsadmin_pwd'] }})
end
```

Output:-

```
     * template[/tmp/kitchen/cache/domain.properties] action create
       - create new file /tmp/kitchen/cache/domain.properties
       - update content in file /tmp/kitchen/cache/domain.properties from none to fa22e0
       --- /tmp/kitchen/cache/domain.properties 2017-01-12 03:30:13.002968715 +0000
       +++ /tmp/kitchen/cache/.chef-domain20170112-11387-1ytkyk2.properties 2017-01-12 03:30:13.002968715 +0000
       @@ -1 +1,4 @@
       +domain_name= mmm
       +admin_url= nnn
       +new_wls_password= xH#3zIS9Q4Hc#B
```

Comment: This worked for me..!!! Thanks a lot @Mrigesh Priyadarshi . Can you please help me on how to do the same with the templates --> The same value i need to pass it to a templates as below                                        template "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/domain.properties" do
source 'domain_properties.erb'
variables  ({
        :domain_name => "#{domain_name}",
        :admin_url => "#{admin_url}",
        :new_wls_password => "#{new_wls_password}" }) --> Here i want to use that value some thing from same json file. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please update the question, its very difficult to read from comment

Comment: @HarishPC - please vote the answer as well so it can be helpful to others too.

Comment: I am getting the following error after trying the approach with the templates                                                                                                               TypeError
    ---------
    no implicit conversion of nil into String followed by variables #<Chef::DelayedEvaluator:0x00000004a11c70@/var/opt/rgbu-chef/cookbooks/rgbu_orase/recipes/orase_password_rotation.rb:50>

Comment: I have tested the code, I have given, and it works fine (updated output). As far as error is concerned, it would require more debugging, but prima facie it looks like some expected string is coming as NIL.

Comment: I have wrongly used the braces. Its worked for me. Thanku so much @ Mrigesh Priyadarshi.